# Drag button text into button on Click function: Unity Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi hope its not too dumb a question. I'm trying to see if i could drag the text in a button onto the on Click method of the button. The drag drop doesn't work.

If not, is the only way on script? Whats the best way to get the text via script?

(The text is added via a script).

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemingly your `DialogueManager.continue` method takes a `string` as parameter

```c#
public void continue(string text)
{
    ...
}
```

-> No! You can't simply drag in a component into a `string` field.

Try to make your method rather take a `Text`/`TMP_Text` component as parameter

```c#
public void continue (Text /* or TMP_Text accordingly*/ text)
{
    Debug.Log(text.text);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I think it is similar to the answer from Guye below, but he gave me a screenshot so i accepted his instead.

Comment: @DanielShen well according to your [newest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70889409/taking-the-text-from-a-gameobject-in-script-unity) about this same matter the accepted answer doesn't fully work for you though ... The screenshot seems pretty redundant to me since you already know exactly what it will look like and what you want to do  ... So I didn't add one since I'm on the phone and can't open unity just to add a screenshot of something you already know anyway ... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: sorry about that~ i tried the UI way first (with GameObject) and then got stuck.. Later came back and saw the 2nd part of your answer. I've switched the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that. The function you are calling needs to take what you want to pass as a parameter though.
So in this example the function is taking a GameObject.

```
public void DialogueButtonPressed(GameObject textGameObject)
{
        
}
```

You can pass whatever type you want though. Maybe you want to pass a UI.Text component.

[image]

Comment: Hi sorry do you mind if i ask a follow up, how do i retrieve the text from the GameObject? It says there is "no definition for text"

Comment: I think I told you exactly what to do in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70883601/7111561) ...